# How use Regular Expressions in Specflow

Tags: c#, specflow

My question is:

How can I write step using regular expression in Specflow?

For example, I want to verify the display of the following message on the web page:

"The contract xxxx has been successfully saved ".

**NB**: The number xxxx can contain numbers and alphabets and it is dynamically generated.

```
Then The message "????" is displayed
```

Thanks.

Comment: so, you are looking for a regex that matches that? ... "The contract [0-9a-zA-Z]*? has been successfully saved "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make your step more focussed on what you expect to happen and less on how it happens:

```
Then I get an indication that the contract has been saved successfully
```

then when you implement that step you can check for the expected message using the regex.

```
Then("I get a message indicating that the contract has been saved")
public void ThenIGetAMessage()
{    
    //pseudo code
    Regex regex = new Regex("The contract [0-9a-zA-Z]+ has been successfully saved"
    regex.Match(result).Should().BeTrue();
}
```

but if you want to include the message matching text in the scenario then there are a couple of options I can think of:

first, just pass the exact regex to match:

```
Then the message "The contract [0-9a-zA-Z]+ has been successfully saved" is displayed
```

and the code would be something like:

```
Then("the message "(.*)" is displayed")
public void ThenIGetAMessage(string regex)
{    
    //pseudo code
    Regex regex = new Regex(regex);
    regex.Match(result).Should().BeTrue();
}
```

or use a place holder for the contract number

```
Then the message "The contract <ContractNumber> has been successfully saved" is displayed
```

and the code would be something like:

```
Then("the message "(.*)" is displayed")
public void ThenIGetAMessage(string regex)
{    
    //pseudo code
    Regex regex = new Regex(regex.Replace("<ContractNumber>","[0-9a-zA-Z]+"));
    regex.Match(result).Should().BeTrue();
}
```

Comment: How can you possibly know that your suggestion is "more business focussed" without seeing the context that the step is used in?

Comment: I meant you should not be dealing with internal implementations in the steps, its about the 'what' should happen not the 'how' it happens. I'll rephrase